# React native : Json parse error: unexpected identifier 'object'

Tags: json, react-native

I was working in React-Native to store js object in Async-storage.

But I am getting the below error,

Can someone show me a way to get rid of this error, please....?

**Code**

```
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

    const data = [
        {key:0, head:"Car Name     :", value: "Ford Figo"},
        {key:1, head:"Car Model    :", value:"1.2 Titanium MT"},
        {key:2, head:"Mfg Year       :", value:"2009"},
        {key:3, head:"Capacity       :", value:"1198 cc"},
        {key:4, head:"Fuel Type     :", value:"Diesel"},
        {key:5, head:"Car Plate      :", value:"TM09EC8364"},
        {key:6, head:"Chassis No  :", value:"MCJGXYMTKIKM30798"},
        {key:7, head:"Engine No    :", value:"KM30798"}
    ];

    const storeData = async (key,value) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('store err: '+e)
        }
    }
    
    const getData = (key) => {
        try {
            const d = AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
            return d != null ? JSON.parse(d) : null;
        } catch(e) {
            console.log('read err: '+e)
        }
      }

    storeData('HomeData',data)
    const Dat= getData('HomeData')
    console.log(Dat)
```

**output**

```
 LOG  read err: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"
 LOG  undefined
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62342675/5708566

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62342611/json-parse-error-unexpected-identifier-object)

Answer (score 0):

@windowsill pointed it out, each method in the AsyncStorage API returns a promise object.  You need to wait it out:

```
const getData = async key => {
try {
    let d = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    d = d ? JSON.parse(d) : null;
    return d;
} catch(e) {
    console.warn(e)
}
```

}